# Postgresql: table name / schema confusion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table `Abc` in the public schema of my postgresql database. According to the documentation `public` should be the default schema. `search_path` is set to `"$user",public` as expected. But the following fails:

```
select * from Abc
```

and this call fails too:

```
select * from public.Abc
```

Both produce an error saying that `relation ... does not exist`. But this one works fine:

```
select * from public."Abc"
```

I'm an experienced T-SQL developer, but new to postgresql. According to the documenation, it should be possible to use "normal" SQL with postgresql. But it does not work in my case. Any hint what I might have messed up!?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Postgresql defaults to lower case characters while being case sensitive with column/table names:

```
select * from public.Abc
```

is actually:

```
select * from public.abc
```

That's because your table is called Abc, so it cannot be found.

You can override this lower case behavior via quotation marks, so "Abc" is handled as Abc.

Comment: A good rule of thumb that I live by in the PG world is use underscores instead of camel case like you might do in Microsoft SQL Server.  So do fast_table instead of "FastTable". I find extra quotes at the minimum to be annoying.  Though others might find underscores to be the same. But I come from and Oracle background so  I'm use to it.

Answer (score 6):

This is normal, object names like tables and columns are case insensitive, unless you put them between double quotes ". This is standard SQL behaviour.

Comment: Just for completeness. Am I right that SQL standard requires that names without quotes should act as same as **upper-cased** quoted equivalent ? In other words `Abc ≡ "ABC"` ?

Comment: @Grzegorz: AFAIK, table and column names are supposed to be normalized to upper case unless quoted; PostgreSQL, OTOH, converts the names to lower case instead.

Answer (score 5):

Don't trust on mixed case. Best for your sanity is never to use mixed case.
The public schema is (mostly) the default schema, and can be omitted.

Comment: The reason for this advice is that you quickly run into problems when your model gets exported to another installation, with other settings for case(in)sensitivity.