# Adodb using php with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, adodb

I have database name "TestDB" and under that I have table called "User".
Above TestDB database and User table have been created in both mysql and postgres.

I have written the following code. it is working for mysql & not working for postgres.

/* The below code is show the output as array with currentuser key value property */ (this is if we execute directly @ postgres prompt it will give the current user query result*/ not the actual table located inside the Testdb */

php code

```
     include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');

     $db = ADONewConnection("mysql"); # eg 'mysql' or 'postgres'

     $db->debug = true;

     $db->Connect(localhost, "mysql", "mysql123","TestDB");

     $rs = $db->Execute('select * from User');

     print "<pre>";

     print_r($rs->GetRows());

     print "</pre>";

     $db1 = ADONewConnection("postgres"); # eg 'mysql' or 'postgres'

     $db1->debug = true;

     $db->Connect(localhost, "postgres", "postgres123","TestDB");

     $rs = $db->Execute('select * from User');

     print "<pre>";

     print_r($rs->GetRows());

     print "</pre>";
```

Please suggest me what to do this.

Comment: I think you posted the same code snippets twice?

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262891/2905135), PostgreSQL defaults to lower case characters while being case sensitive with column and table names.

After the PostgreSQL connection, you could try the following:

```
$rs = $db->Execute('select * from "User"');
```

Comment: fine. it worked. But in this case I can't write single code for mysql as well as postgressql. is it ? how to resolve that?

Comment: You could use only lower case in column and table names.

Comment: Now I have used only lowercase letters for database,tablename,columns. still it is not displaying respective table user

Comment: That is always tricky. Instead do you have consider to use some kind of ORM library, as [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com)? Or a full framework, as [Laravel](http://laravel.com)?

Comment: yes it is working now. i recreated all the database names,tables,column names in lowercase.