# Heroku Database not being read properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am having trouble getting my Heroku app running.  I want to import some data to my heroku database.  I did this by running:

```
heroku pg:psql
\copy tablename FROM 'db/tableInfo.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

then when I run:

```
select* from tablename
```

It prints out all the data I uploaded from the CSV, as desired. 
However, when I go to my app and run "heroku open" my browser shows a page that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong."  Then when I check the heroku logs, it says "PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "tablename" does not exist"
I am confused because when I go to the heroku site it says there are 3 rows (which I uploaded to tablename) and the "select * from tablename" after running heroku pg:psql displayed all the data that I wanted.  Does anyone know why the relation isn't being recognized?
Thanks!
[After running db:migrate I get this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJQza.png)
EDIT: Here is the output from heroku logs (experimentInfo is the table name)

```
2016-03-15T05:33:16.813191+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:33:16.813192+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:33:16.813193+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')
2016-03-15T05:33:16.813801+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered main/experimentHome.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
2016-03-15T05:33:16.813872+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816093+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816105+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816123+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816124+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816126+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:    <%= @mexpMessage %>
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816125+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')):
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816127+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:    <div class="alert alert-warning" style = "color:black" align = "left"><%= "To begin browsing the database, click on one of the experiments listed below.  You can find information about each experiment listed in the blue boxes below each experiment link.  To download the raw data for a given experiment, click the link next to the 'Click to download' field." %></div>
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816128+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <h4> List of Experiments: </h4> 
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816128+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:    <% @experimentList.each do |e| %>
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816130+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:        </a>
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816129+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:        <%= link_to e.title, search_path(:selectexp => e.expId) %>
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816131+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        <div class="alert alert-info">
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816132+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519516940'
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816133+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519516940'
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816134+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/main_controller.rb:6:in `experimentHome'
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816135+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:33:16.816135+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:33:16.805861+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-beach-44318.herokuapp.com request_id=9b7cfa64-a230-4077-b676-96f407bda79a fwd="128.12.253.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=34ms status=500 bytes=1458
2016-03-15T05:38:27.339628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-beach-44318.herokuapp.com request_id=3a672911-5097-46ba-8920-7a307caeef2e fwd="128.12.253.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=1458
2016-03-15T05:38:27.321501+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 128.12.253.5 at 2016-03-15 05:38:27 +0000
2016-03-15T05:38:27.343748+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MainController#experimentHome as HTML
2016-03-15T05:38:27.347286+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist
2016-03-15T05:38:27.347296+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:38:27.347298+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:38:27.347299+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')
2016-03-15T05:38:27.348006+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered main/experimentHome.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
2016-03-15T05:38:27.348212+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350701+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350712+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350712+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350713+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350714+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')):
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350716+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:    <%= @mexpMessage %>
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350718+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:    <div class="alert alert-warning" style = "color:black" align = "left"><%= "To begin browsing the database, click on one of the experiments listed below.  You can find information about each experiment listed in the blue boxes below each experiment link.  To download the raw data for a given experiment, click the link next to the 'Click to download' field." %></div>
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350719+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:    <% @experimentList.each do |e| %>
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350718+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <h4> List of Experiments: </h4> 
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350720+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:        <%= link_to e.title, search_path(:selectexp => e.expId) %>
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350720+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:        </a>
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350721+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        <div class="alert alert-info">
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350722+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519291600'
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350724+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519291600'
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350725+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/main_controller.rb:6:in `experimentHome'
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350725+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:38:27.350726+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:49:37.158759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-beach-44318.herokuapp.com request_id=fe636ea4-c661-4ca3-b5b9-3b8e809f9a42 fwd="128.12.253.5" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=1458
2016-03-15T05:49:37.157464+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 128.12.253.5 at 2016-03-15 05:49:37 +0000
2016-03-15T05:49:37.158827+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MainController#experimentHome as HTML
2016-03-15T05:49:37.162467+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist
2016-03-15T05:49:37.162475+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:49:37.162477+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:49:37.162478+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')
2016-03-15T05:49:37.163383+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered main/experimentHome.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
2016-03-15T05:49:37.163562+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166125+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166138+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166139+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166139+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166140+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')):
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166141+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:    <%= @mexpMessage %>
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166144+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <h4> List of Experiments: </h4> 
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166160+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:    <% @experimentList.each do |e| %>
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166161+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:        <%= link_to e.title, search_path(:selectexp => e.expId) %>
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166161+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:        </a>
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166144+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:    <div class="alert alert-warning" style = "color:black" align = "left"><%= "To begin browsing the database, click on one of the experiments listed below.  You can find information about each experiment listed in the blue boxes below each experiment link.  To download the raw data for a given experiment, click the link next to the 'Click to download' field." %></div>
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166162+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        <div class="alert alert-info">
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166163+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519291600'
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166164+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519291600'
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166165+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/main_controller.rb:6:in `experimentHome'
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166166+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:49:37.166166+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:51:40.692387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-beach-44318.herokuapp.com request_id=4867e943-7dab-40d9-8944-a030c8977e39 fwd="128.12.253.5" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1458
2016-03-15T05:51:40.699721+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 128.12.253.5 at 2016-03-15 05:51:40 +0000
2016-03-15T05:51:40.700884+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MainController#experimentHome as HTML
2016-03-15T05:51:40.706934+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist
2016-03-15T05:51:40.706951+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:51:40.706942+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:51:40.707848+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
2016-03-15T05:51:40.706953+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710357+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:51:40.707677+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered main/experimentHome.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms)
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710386+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710387+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expI...
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710388+00:00 app[web.1]:                                        ^
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710388+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "experimentInfo".* FROM "experimentInfo"  WHERE (expId != 'expId')):
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710389+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:    <%= @mexpMessage %>
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710391+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:    <div class="alert alert-warning" style = "color:black" align = "left"><%= "To begin browsing the database, click on one of the experiments listed below.  You can find information about each experiment listed in the blue boxes below each experiment link.  To download the raw data for a given experiment, click the link next to the 'Click to download' field." %></div>
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710392+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <h4> List of Experiments: </h4> 
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710393+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:    <% @experimentList.each do |e| %>
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710393+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:        <%= link_to e.title, search_path(:selectexp => e.expId) %>
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710394+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:        </a>
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710395+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        <div class="alert alert-info">
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710396+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519516940'
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710397+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/main/experimentHome.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_main_experiment_ome_html_erb___1511755932124521423_70162519516940'
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710399+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710398+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/main_controller.rb:6:in `experimentHome'
2016-03-15T05:51:40.710400+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error log?

Comment: Done, sorry the formatting is weird, not sure how to fix that.  I saw the line " PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "experimentInfo" does not exist" and assumed that was the error

Comment: Did you try `heroku run rake db:migrate` and are you sure there is a migration to create that table?

Comment: I used "heroku pg:psql -a your-app-name <db/structure.sql" to create the database.  I haven't run "heroku run rake: db:migrate" since I thought the above code would create my table for me.  Also when I ran heroku pg:psql and then "select * from experimentInfo;" it printed out some information, so I think the table exists

Comment: Just try running the migrations once. And as you are saying the table exists then once do check the database name on heroku and the database name you rails app is using.

Comment: I did that, but now something weird is happening.  I added a picture at the top of the post, but essentially it says under tables that there is a table named "experimentInfo" but now I can't add data to that table for some reason

Comment: The image shows that the table name is `experimentInfo` and you are trying to add data in `experimentinfo` and these names are case sensitive. I guess this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262795/postgresql-table-name-schema-confusion

Comment: But I wrote "\copy experimentInfo FROM 'db/exp1/expInfo1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;" (notice the capitalization).  Why is it making the "I" lowercase?

Comment: That is pg's default behavior I think. See the link shared in previous comment that might help you as I don't have much experience in PG.